# How to subscribe to date chage with Rxjs

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive

I couldn't find a "simple" example with Rxjs, demonstrating how we can listen to days changes as an event.

for example, let's say that I have to execute certain methods every time we enter a new day. how can I approach this with the reactive paradigm and subscribe to time events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this by creating an observable that is deferred until the subscription happens which then, calculates the time and looks for the nearest future midnight to emit an event.

```
function newSolarDayObserver() {
    return defer(() => {
      const timeAtSubscription = new Date();
      const nextDay = new Date();
      // get the nearest midnight in future
      nextDay.setHours(24, 0, 0, 0);
      const initialDelay = nextDay.getTime() - timeAtSubscription.getTime();
      // repeat every 24 hours and 1 minute
      const repeat = 1000 * 60 * 61 * 24;
      return timer(initialDelay, repeat);
    });
  }
```

this observable can then be used with the `reapeatWhen` operator to repeat a previous stream when a new day event is emitted.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `timer();` or `interval()` Observable which can emit at any interval you want and on every emition check for current day. F.ex. this will check for current day every second:

```
timer(0, 1000).pipe(
  tap(() => {
    const date = new Date();
    const currentDay = date.getDate();
  })
)
```

Makes not so much sense to check for current day every second, but maybe current time is one second before the next day, so might be needed. To improve this, you could switch to new Observable when day has changed which will emit after 23 hours 59 minutes:

```
const source$ = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
  switchMap(() => {
    const dayState = this.getDayState();

    if (dayState && dayState.ends) {
      return timer(0, (1000 * 60 * 60 * 23) + (1000 * 60 * 59)).pipe(
        switchMap(() => this.source$)
      )
    } 
    return this.source$;
  })
)

function getDayState(): {stars?: boolean, ends?: boolean} {
  const date = new Date();
  const hours = date.getHours();
  const minutes = date.getMinutes();

  if (hours === 23 && minutes === 59) {
    return { ends: true };
  } else if (hours === 0 && minutes === 1) {
    return { starts: true };
  }
}
```

This is very rough example. Also, at the moment I don't know how browser would handle this long lived subscription. You might need to do some workarounds, like force browser reload or add other checks so you can rely on this stream. Also, instead of using `getDayState()` function, more reliable way would be to store last day and check when current day is different.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this answer.